# NameError: name 'page_num' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

#passing path of Pdf file will open a pdf reader window

```
def text_extract(path):
page_num = 0  # variable assignment
root = Tk()   tkinter wiindow
pdf = PdfFileReader(path)  
def page_update(page_num):           #function to update text gui on the basis of page number
    page_obj = pdf.getPage(page_num)
    txt = page_obj.extractText()
    text_wig.delete("1.0", "end")
    text_wig.insert(END,txt)
def page_prev(e=1):        #to see previous page
    global page_num
    if page_num <= 0:
        messagebox.showinfo('Alert','Its a first page')
    else:
        page_num = page_num -1
        page_update(page_num)
def page_next(e=1):        # for next page
    global page_num
    if page_num >= pdf.numPages:
        messagebox.showinfo('Alert','Its a last page')
    else:
        page_num = page_num + 1
        page_update(page_num)


Button(root, text='Prev',command = page_prev).grid(row=0, column=1)
Button(root, text='Next',command = page_next).grid(row=0, column=2)
page_obj = pdf.getPage(page_num)
txt = page_obj.extractText()
text_wig = Text(root)
text_wig.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=10,columnspan=10)
text_wig.delete("1.0", "end")
text_wig.insert(END,txt)
root.mainloop()
```

#this is showing the only  first page of pdf next or  prev buttons are not working

Comment: Fix the code indentation first.  BTW, since `page_num` seems to be declared inside `text_extract()` and both `prev_page()` and `next_page()` are defined inside the function as well, you need to use `nonlocal` instead of `global`.

Comment: nonlocal is working perfectly fine thanks

Answer (score 0):

if there is a value inside a function and you need to use it or edit it outside the function you'll have to write `global page_num` before defining or editing it